# How to find if a series is convergent given the following data?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I solve these type of questions and what are the correct answers for this one?
Sorry I'm not familiar with formatting math symbols so I attached an example question as an image.

[Example question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjCU4.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to either show that the given series are termwise-smaller than either $ \sum_{n} a_n$, $\sum_n b_n$ or $\sum_n a_n + b_n$, which are all convergent, or find a counterexample.